# Don't know why Name is not defined for greatest common divisor function

Tags: python

Im trying to create a function that allows fractions with different denominators to use the + operator, while simplifying the result to the fraction divisible by the greatest common divisor for numerator and denominator.

```
class Fraction:

    def __init__(self, top, bottom):
        self.num = top
        self.den = bottom


    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.num) + "/" + str(self.den)

    def gcd(m, n):
        while m%n != 0:
            oldm = m
            oldn = n

            m = oldn
            n = oldm%oldn
        return n


    def __add__(self, otherFraction):
        newnum = self.num*otherFraction.den + \
                 self.den*otherFraction.num
        newden = self.den*otherFraction.den
        common = gcd(newnum, newden)

        return Fraction(newnum//common, newden//common)

f1 = Fraction(1,4)
f2 = Fraction(1,2)

f3 = f1+f2
print(f3)
```

I expected the output to be `3/4` and was given the following error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\matth\Desktop\MandRfraction.py", line 35, in <module>
    f3 = f1+f2
  File "C:\Users\matth\Desktop\MandRfraction.py", line 28, in __add__
    common = gcd(newnum//common, newden//common)
NameError: name 'gcd' is not defined
```

I don't know why gcd is not defined.

Comment: Because it's `Fraction.gcd()`

Comment: `gcd()` is a method, so you need to call it by `common = self.gcd(...)`

Comment: It also looks like `gcd` could just as well be a module-scoped function instead of living in the `Fraction` class.

Comment: @kstullich That's not right, it doesn't take a `self` parameter.

Comment: @kstullich that won't work, it expects integer arguments, not `Fraction`s and will try and pass three args

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a class-specific function aka "method" (defined inside the `Fraction` class), so you need to call it as `Fraction.gcd` instead of just `gcd`.

Since it's a *static* function (not connected to any individual `Fraction`), it's also good practice to mark it as such:

```
@staticmethod
def gcd(m, n):
    return ...
```

Now you can call it as `self.gcd(...)` (inside any `Fraction` method), or as `Fraction.gcd(...)` (anywhere at all).

Comment: It's not a "local function", it's a method, a very different object. It's also not just "good practice" -- you should explain that with `@staticmethod` it can (and **should**) be called with `self`.

Comment: I'm not sure about "applies to the Fraction class as a whole". Python has _class methods_, but this is not that.  It doesn't apply to the class at all. It's just been placed inside the class (for some reason).

Comment: @khelwood Edited to rephrase